# Pillow library in python Discord BOT doesn't recognise the .paste and .save functions

Tags: python, image-processing, discord, discord.py, python-imaging-library

I'm searching to do a custom welcome image with my discord bot and the pillow python library.
I can't understand why this code isn't working. I'm going crazy...

(If there is some confusion with the name of the variables don't worry because I had to translate this code before)

```
import discord
import datetime
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
from discord import client, message
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
client.remove_command('help')


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.avatar_url.save('test.png')
    pfp_unresized = Image.open('test.png')
    pfp = pfp_unresized.resize((200, 200))

    graph = Image.open("graph.png")
    black_img = Image.open("Black_img.png")

    bannerpfp = black_img.paste(pfp, (400, 30))
    bannernotxt = bannerpfp.paste(graph, (0, 0))

    await bannernotxt.save('bannernotxt.png')
```

This is the traceback:

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\users\yuppi\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\yuppi\Documents\Nico\Codici\PYTHON\Discord\DiscordBOT\DiscordBOT.py", line 33, in on_member_join
    bannernotxt = bannerpfp.paste(graph, (0, 0))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'paste'
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: [`Image.paste`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste) is an **inplace** operation that will change `black` and return `None`

Comment: It is also `black_img.paste` not `black.paste`

Comment: @LukasThaler can you explain this better please?

Comment: @Ceres Yes I know, but I translated all the variables in english so it can be that some names are incorrect.

Comment: After your call to `black_img.paste(pfp, (400, 30))`, the original `black_img` variable contains the modified image. You don't need to store the return value, as it'll always be `None` and can continue with `black_img`. I'll add an answer outlining the idea in a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noted in the comments, [`Image.paste`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste) operates **in place**, i.e. it modifies the *existing* variable instead of returning a modified version of it. The return value for such functions is always `None`, because nothing is being returned.

---

For your specific case, this means that calling `black_img.paste(pfp, (400, 30))` will modify `black_img` directly. If you check the image before and after this call, you'll notice that they are different. Accordingly, modifying your code to the following should leave you with the desired result:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.avatar_url.save('test.png')
    pfp_unresized = Image.open('test.png')
    pfp = pfp_unresized.resize((200, 200))

    graph = Image.open("graph.png")
    black_img = Image.open("Black_img.png")

    black_img.paste(pfp, (400, 30))
    black_img.paste(graph, (0, 0))

    await black_img.save('bannernotxt.png')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro.. 
I have another little question, as I seen the pillow library doesn't permit the clear background... Is there any way to make this thing possible or I have to reshape the image?

Comment: Pillow supports transparent pixels, but you need to convert the file to [`RGBA`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes) like so: `Image.open('filename.png').convert('RGBA')`